# Checking mySQL database (of links) for matching links

Tags: php, mysql, rss

I am trying to figure out how I can check my mySQL database (that is comprised of 4 columns, herein one of them being links fed by an RSS feed) for links that have already been inserted.

Ultimately i want to run an if else statement where I check the rss feed, and only add new links to my database.

So to clarify, my question is: What can I use to check if a links is already existing in my mySQL database, and then only write in new data if the link is unique?

Comment: Do you even know how to query your DB and update it, what have your tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample :

```
$url="http://example.com";
$sql=$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE url=?");
$sql->execute(array($url));
if($sql->rowCount()==0){
 $sql=$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO table (url) VALUES(?)");
 $sql->execute(array($url));
}else{
 echo "URL Exists";
}
```

More About PDO : [php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: You shouldn't be using/promoting `MySQL_` because of its deprecation. The use of `MySQLi_` and/or PDO is recommended.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Oh Sorry, I forgot that. Updated Code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Insert into mytable (col1, col2, col3, linkcol) 
Select "col1 value","c2v","col3v","link" 
from mytable 
where col1 = "value known to exist and be unique" 
and not exists 
(
   select col1 
   from mytable mt2 
   where my2.linkcol = "link"
)
```